# Is there any way to have findstr read from back to front?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have this batch script:

```
@ECHO OFF

SETLOCAL
set fullName=%*
Set "dotstr=."
Set "slashstr=\\"

SET stemp=%fullName%&SET pos=0
:loop
SET /a pos+=1
echo %stemp%|FINDSTR /b /c:"%slashstr%" >NUL
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (
SET stemp=%stemp:~1%
IF DEFINED stemp GOTO loop
SET pos=0
)

ECHO Pos of "%slashstr%" IN "%fullName%" = %pos%


SET dtemp=%fullName%&SET postwo=0
:dloop
SET /a postwo+=1
echo %dtemp%|FINDSTR /b /c:"%dotstr%" >NUL
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (
SET dtemp=%dtemp:~1%
IF DEFINED dtemp GOTO dloop
SET postwo=0
)

ECHO Pos of "%dotstr%" IN "%fullName%" = %postwo%

pause
```

A dragged in file with the full directory and extension gets assigned to fullName, and I want findstr to find the last instance of "\".

Is there any way I can read backwards using findstr? I see nothing in the API about reading backwards. Thank you!

Comment: This appears to me like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/); see also [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should state what you are really after, the extension, filename without extension, parent folder name? There are better ways to obtain these.

- instead of iterating the input twice, do check twice with substrings
- the characters looked for could occure more than once.

---

```
@Echo off
SetLocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
set "fullname=%*"
set "PosDot="
set "PosSlash="
Set /A Ofs=0,Pos=1
:loop
if "!fullname:~%Ofs%,1!" equ "" Goto :NextStep
if "!fullname:~%Ofs%,1!" equ "." Set PosDot=%PosDot%,%Pos%
if "!fullname:~%Ofs%,1!" equ "\" Set PosSlash=%PosSlash%,%Pos%
set /A Pos+=1,Ofs+=1
Goto :loop
:NextStep
Echo:1234567890123456789012345678901234567890
Echo:%fullname%
Echo Pos of . %PosDot:~1%
Echo Pos of \ %PosSlash:~1%
```

Sample output with own filename

```
> SO_44768306.cmd Q:\Test\2017\06\26\SO_44768306.cmd
1234567890123456789012345678901234567890
Q:\Test\2017\06\26\SO_44768306.cmd
Pos of . 31
Pos of \ 3,8,13,16,19
```